# this code is not working showing KeyError: 'Percentage'

Tags: python

## Pivot table

```
print(np.unique(data['AIRLINE']))
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['DAY_OF_WEEK', 'ORIGIN_AIRPORT', 'DESTINATION_AIRPORT'],
                       values=['Percentage'],
                      aggfunc=np.average).plt()
print(pivot)
```

Comment: I've just modified the formatting, but it still looks weird. Can you check if everything is well formatted? (You might know that indentation is key in Python)

Comment: what do you have in `df` ?